# Initial route is not initial

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an app. It has no problem on my android device. But it fails on chrome.
I use chrome for debug purpose so this actually prevents me from debugging without a device.
And maybe it has problem on other devices too. I don't know for sure.

This is my routes in my main.dart's route widget.

```
  initialRoute: '/splash',
      routes: {
        '/': (context) => const HomePage(),
        '/splash': (context) => const SplashPage(),
        '/about': (context) => const AboutPage(),
        '/list': (context) => const ListPage(),
        '/favorites': (context) => const FavoritesPage(),
      },
```

I have some initialization in the SplashScreen like

```
class SplashPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SplashPage({super.key});

initApp(context) async {
await initThis ...
await initThat ...
// another inits

  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/");
} 

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    initApp(context);

    return Container(
    //....

}
```

When I start debugging on chrome, from the debugPrints I have, I notice that HomePage widget is running before SplashPage. Then it stops in SplashPage without going forward. That's because my HomePage's Build method is running before my SplashPage and I don't know why. I looked at flutter's life cycle but It's all about a one widget and it doesn't say much about route life cycle.

I tried changing Navigator.pushReplacementNamed to Navigator.popAndPushNamed but it doesn't change anyhting. No matter what I do, HomePage is building itself behind the scenes.

Comment: read this carefully: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/initialRoute.html (the most important is 3rd paragraph)

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your initial route `/splash` to the `/` because on the web initial route always be a `/`.

```
 initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    '/home': (context) => const HomePage(),
    '/': (context) => const SplashPage(),
    '/about': (context) => const AboutPage(),
    '/list': (context) => const ListPage(),
    '/favorites': (context) => const FavoritesPage(),
  },
```

Just change it like this and use `/home` route for the home page instead of `/`.

Comment: Thank you but it wasn't actually because of this , I just removed the / like pskink said and it worked